# Export termstore from SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint, metadata

I'm trying to get an export of our Taxonomy in SharePoint Online.  It was input manually.  There doesn't appear to be any option for exporting in the term store management tool, although you can import from a CSV.  Is there a simple way of exporting the term store without manually copying and pasting each individual term?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Taxonomy Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.webservices.taxonomyclientservice%28v=office.15%29.aspx). Though it isn't the easiest of things to get your head around and will need the support of a developer probably.

You can get it via the URL:

```
https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/taxonomyclientservice.asmx
```